# Keyboard doesn't work in chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard

Sometimes the keyboard simply stops working in Chrome.
When I open Chrome for the first time it works fine, but if I minimize it and use any other application, and return to Chrome, the keyboard stops working.
After that, if I write something in `notepad` or any other and then try to write something in Chrome again, it starts working again.
So the flow is:

- when I launch Chrome for the first time the keyboard works fine. Then
- if Chrome remains idle for sometime, the keyboard stops working and I can't write anything in a textbox, chatbox or the address bar.
- then, if I use any other program where can I give input via keyboard, and return to Chrome, it starts working again.

What I tried:

- clearing browser **data**, **cache** and even **reinstalling**.

> **Note:** My OS is Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: I am facing same problem. I think its not chrome its with windows 10 
with me its happening with every program. You think its chrome because you might spend most of the time on chrome.. I thought that also that it was chrome only.. But later i noticed it was with all programs. I am having this issue with both my laptop and computer Windows 10

You don't have to right write in notepad to make it work. Just switch programs or click outside program and it will start working again

Comment: Me too with avast extension.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off Scroll Lock.

If you don't have such key on your keyboard, then start a desktop keyboard and turn it off there.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Answer (score -2):

Do you, by any chance, have an antivirus extension installed (ie Kaspersky) ?

I was having the same problems (used to click 'log out' to close windows session to get the keyboard back to work) and it has been fixed after removal of Kaspersky virtual keyboard extension + unsync Chrome with google account.

Do NOT allow Chrome background process by the way

So please try 'incognito mode' (CTRL + SHIFT + N) : it will deactivate extensions and you'll see whether it helped or not.

Hope it will help

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: no , I do not use kaspersky or any other antivirus